# Adding urls/views to a model - Django Oscar?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I want to add some urls/views to `dashboard` app. So I forked the app using `oscar_fork_app`. I have created an `app.py` file in forked `dashboard`app folder. Also added an `app.py` inside `catalogue` sub-app inside `dashboard` app.  Following [this](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/how_to_change_a_url.html).
My `#dashboard/app.py`

```
from oscar.apps.dashboard.app import DashboardApplication as CoreDashboardApplication


class DashboardApplication(CoreDashboardApplication):
    name = 'dashboard'
    permissions_map = {
        'index': (['is_staff'], ['partner.dashboard_access']),
    }

    index_view = get_class('dashboard.views', 'IndexView')
    catalogue_app = get_class('dashboard.catalogue.app', 'application')


    def get_urls(self):
        urls = [
            url(r'^catalogue/', include(self.catalogue_app.urls)),
        ]
        return self.post_process_urls(urls)


application = DashboardApplication()
```

My `#dashboard/catalogue/app.py`

```
from oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue.app import CatalogueApplication as CoreCatalogueApplication


class CatalogueApplication(CoreCatalogueApplication):
    name = None
    csv_upload_view = get_class('dashboard.catalogue.views',
                                 'CSVUpload')

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = [
            url(r'^csvupload/$',
                self.csv_upload_view.as_view(),
                name='csvupload'),
        ]
        return self.post_process_urls(urls)


application = CatalogueApplication()
```

when I hit `/dashboard` it says

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/dashboard/
Using the URLconf defined in teashop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^i18n/
^admin/
^accounts/reviews/$ [name='review-list']
^accounts/subscriptions/$ [name='subscriptions']
^accounts/storecredit/$ [name='storecredit']
^catalogue/
^basket/
^checkout/
^accounts/
^search/
^dashboard/ ^catalogue/
^offers/
The current URL, dashboard/, didn't match any of these.
```

Do I have to copy paste all the urls in oscar.apps.dashboard.app to my forked_app ? What's the way to extend in the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add all the urls of the parent class.

```
class DashboardApplication(CoreDashboardApplication):
    ...
    catalogue_app = get_class('dashboard.catalogue.app', 'application')


    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(DashboardApplication, self).get_urls()  
        urls += [
            url(r'^catalogue/', include(self.catalogue_app.urls)),
        ]
        return self.post_process_urls(urls)
```

Similarly for the other app.py

```
class CatalogueApplication(CoreCatalogueApplication):
    name = None
    csv_upload_view = get_class('dashboard.catalogue.views',
                                 'CSVUpload')

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(CatalogueApplication, self).get_urls()
        urls += [
            url(r'^csvupload/$',
                self.csv_upload_view.as_view(),
                name='csvupload'),
        ]
        return self.post_process_urls(urls)


application = CatalogueApplication()
```